# Ceiling fan electrical conundrum

Tags: ceiling-fan

I am attempting to install a ceiling fan in an area that previously had a light fixture. I have installed the support and box. The ceiling has 2 of the old (cloth, both black) wires coming out of it. When I install the fan with the motor and light wires connected to one side, neutral to the other it doesn't work. it has power as I hardwired another light and that works. I also put an extension cord on the fan and plugged it into a wall socket so I know that works as well. as a side note, with fan wired, flipping switch will cause a "crackle" in my surround sound system in the next room over.  Any thoughts? Thanks.

Comment: How do you know which is neutral? The motor may require specific polarity.

Comment: On top of the polarity, The crackle could be a loose or broken wire arcing.

Comment: I have to ask - just in case - but does your fan have pull-cord switches - and did you pull one or both of them ... ?